# How to replace radio button with unicode character?

Tags: html, unicode, radio-button

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3ft0b0k/

How do I make the unicode characters beside each radio button act like radio button and in other word, change the default radio  button style to the unicode?
HTML

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
<li>
<input type="radio" name="good_bad" value="good" style="visibility:none;"><div style="border:1px solid #00FF00;border-radius:16px;padding:0.5px;font-size:2.5em;color:#00FF00;">&#9786;</div>
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="good_bad" value="bad" style="visibility:none;"><div style="border:1px solid #FF0000;border-radius:16px;padding:0.5px;font-size:2.5em !important;color:#FF0000;">&#9785;</div> 
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand it correctly but how about this:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
<li>
<label><div style="border:1px solid #00FF00;border-radius:16px;padding:0.5px;font-size:2.5em;color:#00FF00;"><input type="radio" name="good_bad" value="good" style="visibility:none;">&#9786;</div></label>
</li>
<li>
<label><div style="border:1px solid #FF0000;border-radius:16px;padding:0.5px;font-size:2.5em !important;color:#FF0000;"><input type="radio" name="good_bad" value="bad" style="visibility:none;">&#9785;</div></label>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: your example shows both radio button and smiley unicode..But I want smiley shown in the place of radio button

Comment: &#9785 and &#9786 are ☹ and ☺

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
html{
    font-size:11px;
}
form select, form input[type="text"]{
    padding:3px 5px;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    line-height:1;
    font-size:2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight:300;
}
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    line-height:1;
    font-size:2rem;
    margin-right:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight:300;
    outline:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:focus,input[type="radio"]:focus{
    outline:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:after, input[type="radio"]:after{
    font-size:inherit;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:3px 5px;
    margin-right:0px !important;
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-right:0px;
    line-height:1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight:300;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:after{
    content:"\2610";
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after{
    content:"\2611";
}
input[type="radio"]:after{
    content:"\25CE";
}
input[type="radio"]:checked:after{
    content:"\25C9";
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label[for],input[type="radio"] + label[for]{
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:3px 5px;
    margin: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:0px;
    margin-left:0px !important;
    line-height:1;
    font-size:2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight:300;
}
::placeholder{
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="text" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="c" /><label for="c">Check me</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r" value="1" id="r1" /><label for="r1">option 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r" value="2" id="r2" /><label for="r2">option 2</label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

It uses existing Unicode characters for radio-buttons and checkboxes (checkboxes have at least a couple of options for checked boxes, radio-buttons—currently—have no unchecked character, so a circle is used). It uses the `:before` and `:content` CSS selectors and attributes to style the labels for the `input` elements and just hides the input elements themselves (clicking the labels will toggle the inputs).

```css
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label,
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 32px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label::before {
    content: "";
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
    content: "☐";
    color: DodgerBlue;
    font-size: 40px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
    content: "";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    content: "☒"; /* or ☑ */
}
```

```html
<input id="a" type="radio" name="gb" value="good1" style="visibility:none;"><label for="a">A</label>
<input id="b" type="radio" name="gb" value="bad1" style="visibility:none;"><label for="b">B</label>

<input id="c" type="checkbox" name="gb" value="good" style="visibility:none;"><label for="c">C</label>
<input id="d" type="checkbox" name="gb" value="bad2" style="visibility:none;"><label for="d">D</label>
```

Comment: (You can also use `url()` to use images instead of Unicode text, but that defeats the point, but at it would provide an option for more consistent visuals.)